# How do you create a matrix using the following vectors?

Tags: r

You have the three vectors below. Write R code to create a matrix using these three vectors binding by columns. Submit (1) your R code and (2) the output (print) of the object in the Console window:

here are the three vectors below.

```
v1 <-c(100001,
100002,
100003,
100004,
100005,
100006,
100007,
100008,
100009
)

v2 <-c(800.64,
217.53,
74.58,
498.6,
723.11,
69.43,
40.15,
58.61,
364.63
)
v3 <-c(3,
3,
2,
3,
4,
2,
2,
2,
2
)
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Take a look at `?matrix` and `?cbind`. Also, this smells a lot like [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: yes i tried using a matrix but i cannot get the syntax right :(

Comment: You should show what you tried :)

Comment: here is what i tried,

Comment: v1 <-c(100001,
       100002,
       100003,
       100004,
       100005,
       100006,
       100007,
       100008,
       100009
)

v2 <-c(800.64,
       217.53,
       74.58,
       498.6,
       723.11,
       69.43,
       40.15,
       58.61,
       364.63
)
v3 <-c(3,
       3,
       2,
       3,
       4,
       2,
       2,
       2,
       2
) 

c(v1,v2,v3)
+   nrow=9, 
+   ncol=3)

Comment: B = matrix(
+ c(v1,v2,v3),
+   nrow=9, 
+   ncol=3)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
matrix(c(v1,v2,v3), ncol=3)
        [,1]   [,2] [,3]
 [1,] 100001 800.64    3
 [2,] 100002 217.53    3
 [3,] 100003  74.58    2
 [4,] 100004 498.60    3
 [5,] 100005 723.11    4
 [6,] 100006  69.43    2
 [7,] 100007  40.15    2
 [8,] 100008  58.61    2
 [9,] 100009 364.63    2
```